# What wrong with my C code? Is it a compiler bug in CodeBlock 16.01?

Tags: c, while-loop, codeblocks

I am using Code::Block 16.01, the current version, that come with compiler. The problem is when I change **xMax** to **1.2**, the result does not change. It produce the same result as **xMax=1.1**. Did I do something wrong with my C code? Or is this a compiler problem? Here is my MWE:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double xMin=1.0;
    double xMax=1.1;
    double x=xMin;
    double h=0.1;
    while(x <= xMax)
    {
        printf("x=%f\n",x);
        x=x+h;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And "*the same result*" is?

Comment: "Is it a compiler bug" no it isn't.

Comment: These constants cannot be exactly represented as floating point numbers.  The `%f` format doesn't display very much precision, but if you look more closely, you will see that `0.1` is actually slightly larger than the intended number.

Comment: @alk: the result of my code is **1.000000**, **1.100000**. And if we let **xMax=1.2**, then the result is the same as the case **xMax=1.1**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a float point precision problem. Since `1.2` cannot be represented exactly in the binary form, there is a precision loss. Your code should work if you change `1.2` to something bigger, let's say, `1.201`

In general, please try to avoid `=` in float point comparisons.

Comment: It depends. It was greater with my compiler. I tried it here: http://ideone.com/

Comment: No. I say that in both cases it printed only two lines: `x=1.000000` and
`x=1.100000`

Comment: Sorry, my original comment was backwards.  Here's what I meant to say:  `1.0`, plus `0.1`, plus `0.1` is *greater than* `1.2`, so the last intended iteration is skipped.  Actually this is consistent with what you posted.  I think I misread it originally.

Comment: Yes. But it does not matter is it less or greater. The problem is the same - `precision`

Comment: Well, it affects the observed behavior.  If it had been the other way around, the problem would not have been noticed.

Comment: Correct. I know some financial applications where there is no floating point numbers at all. All calculations are performed with integers and the results represented as `dddd.dddd`

Comment: Yes, fixed point representations avoid the problem.  It's not just an issue of precision.  Any base 2 floating point representation would have the same problem, regardless of how many bits of precision the mantissa can hold.